# Using update mode with the SDE30 writer in FME

Tags: enterprise-geodatabase, fme-form

I'm recieving the following error when performing an Update operation against a table in ArcSDE using the FME 2011 and the SDE30 writer.

> Error retrieving dbtune keyword list:SDE_ERROR_CODE(-66) Invalid parameter value passed to function

Any ideas why this might be?

The table was created using the geodatabase writer in FME 2011.

**UPDATE 13/11/2014**

I have created a small test harness which is reproducing the error.

> If I switch the sde30 writer to:
>
> > table exists = yes
>
> then the error goes away,

although the update doesn't work - an insert operation happens instead even with writer in UPDATE mode and fme_db_operation exposed and set to 'UPDATE', however when i switch back to table exists=no, the error comes back.

Answer (score 1):

Update will update if the key exists, or insert if it doesn't.

I think that the error you are seeing when you say 'exists=no' is sensible, so you want to set it as 'exists=yes' and sort out the problem of why it's inserting rather than updating.

Have you added the attribute to your writer of the key that you are using to update on? And if so, have you flagged that as the 'SQL Key Columns' or equivalent on the writer?